# Confusion about translate() function while using it for xpath case insensitivity

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, case-insensitive

I am automating a page using selenium with java and trying to use a case insensitive xpath with the help of translate function as follows.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'tools')]")).click();
```

'tools' text exists on the page as 'Tools'. [T as caps]

Now my question is,

- What does '.,' means in the above code?
- Using 'tools' in place of '.,' gives all the //a links. Reason?
- Whenever I use 'Tools' instead of 'tools' in the above code, it does not work.

Someone help me here.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuIff.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuIff.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is,
>
> - What does '.,' means in the above code?
> - Using 'tools' in place of '.,' gives all the //a links. Reason?
> - Whenever I use 'Tools' instead of 'tools' in the above code, it does    not work.

The dot step is an abbreviated syntax, from the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev):

> `.` selects the context node

Because it's used as parameter for a function that expects a string, will be casted by the means of `string()` function.

The string `'tools'` always contains the string `'tools'`, thus you are not filtering any selected `a` element when you used instead of `.`

In the other hand, any lowercase string will never contain the string `'Tools'`, so you won't be able to select anything.